# Surrounding Nodes with an Ellipse in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code places six nodes along the perimeter of an equilateral triangle:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}] 

\node (l1) at (0,0) [circle] {};
\node (l2) at (2,0) [circle] {};
\node (l3) at (4,0) [circle] {};
\node (m1) at (1, 1.732) [circle] {};
\node (m2) at (3, 1.732) [circle] {};
\node (h1) at (2, 3.464) [circle] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I surround each "leg" of the triangle with an ellipse in a manner similar to the following:

[image]

Comment: The `fit` library could help here, but it doesn’t try to be intelligent and does not account for rotating. Have you tried to manually draw the ellipses? There is a shape called `ellipse` as well as the path operatore `ellipse`/`circle`. The `calc` library can help to let TikZ calculate all necessary steps.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One possibility using the `calc` library to draw some rotated ellipses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}] 
\node (l1) at (0,0) [circle] {};
\node (l2) at (2,0) [circle] {};
\node (l3) at (4,0) [circle] {};
\node (m1) at (1, 1.732) [circle] {};
\node (m2) at (3, 1.732) [circle] {};
\node (h1) at (2, 3.464) [circle] {};
\draw let \p1=(h1), \p2=(l1), \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}, \n2={veclen(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}
  in ($ (h1)!0.5!(l1) $) ellipse [x radius=\n2/2+20pt, y radius=0.7cm,rotate=90-\n1];
\draw let \p1=(h1), \p2=(l3), \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}, \n2={veclen(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}
  in ($ (h1)!0.5!(l3) $) ellipse [x radius=\n2/2+20pt, y radius=0.7cm,rotate=90-\n1];
\draw let \p1=(l1), \p2=(l3), \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}, \n2={veclen(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}
  in ($ (l1)!0.5!(l3) $) ellipse [x radius=\n2/2+20pt, y radius=0.7cm,rotate=90-\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for making this solution fairly general. I have been able to modify it for various shapes that arise in my illustrations. It has been a great help in my current endeavor.

Comment: @AustinMohr You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Gonzalo's answer, I wrote myself a little command

```
\newcommand{\fitellipsis}[2] % first and second node names without parentheses
{\draw let \p1=(#1), \p2=(#2), \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}, \n2={veclen(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}
    in ($ (\p1)!0.5!(\p2) $) ellipse [x radius=\n2/2+1cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=\n1];
}
```

that does the trick reliably. The added (cm) units can be adjusted to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Following code uses an equilateral triangle made with a `regular polygon` node. This node is not drawn but their anchors are used to easily place the dots. Ellipses are drawn with a `fit` node. As all ellipses are equal they are build with same `fitting` points but placed and rotated according to desired positions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    myellipse/.style={
        fit=(a.corner 2) (a.corner 3), 
        draw, ellipse, 
        inner xsep=0mm, 
        inner ysep=3mm}]

\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, inner sep=1cm] (a) {};

\foreach \i in {1, 2, 3}{
\fill[red] (a.side \i) circle (2pt);
\fill[red] (a.corner \i) circle (2pt);
}

\node[myellipse] {};
\node[myellipse, rotate=120] at (a.side 3) {};
\node[myellipse, rotate=60] at (a.side 1) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]